# How to fix the postion of blocks while changing images in beamer presentation?

Tags: animation, latex, beamer

I would like to make an animation using beamer. A picture should replace another during the transition. I have a problem that the text will move its position during this animation. I have tried \only and \onslide but the question is not solved.

```
\begin{frame}{}
\onslide<1->{some text }
 \onlide<1>{
 \begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4in]{Figures/fig1.pdf}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
}
\onslide<2->{
\begin{figure}[H]
  \centering
  \includegraphics[,width=4in]{Figures/fig2.pdf}
\label{fig2}
\end{figure}
}


\end{frame}
```

The position of "some text" moves during animation.

Answer (score 2):

- your code has many unprotected line endings (missing `%` at the end of lines) that act like a space
- `onlide` should be `onslide`
- `\onslide<>` makes the content just invisible, but still reserves space. You want to use `\only` instead
- floating specifier such as `[H]` don't make sense in a documentclass without floating mechanism
- `\centering` is unnecessary, beamer figures are centred by default
- you must not use the same lable multiple times
- `\includeggraphics` is overlay aware, just use that and avoid all the other pitfalls:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
\begin{figure}
  \includegraphics<+>[width=4in]{example-image}
  \includegraphics<+>[width=4in]{example-image-duck}
\end{figure}
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank you for your help. Since fig 1 and fig 2 are of different sizes, the text position will still be modified during the transition.

Comment: @CSI Use beamer's `overlayarea` for this